# Support from iOS 4.3/ iOS 5 onwards

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, autolayout, backwards-compatibility

I am planning to use different storyboards (one with and another without autolayout) because I need to have my app from 4.3 to 5.0(without autolayout) and 6.0 onwards (with autolayout) but I cannot build it on my device as I'm failed by

```
Illegal Configuration: Auto Layout on iOS Versions prior to 6.0
```

I don't think I should disable my storyboard autolayout as I got another storyboard to cater the old devices.
How do I able to manage this?

**Note: regarding why I need to support the iOS 4.3 / 5, I cannot make the decision as my business management made that decision. If I support iOS 5 onwards, is there a way to counter for this?**

Comment: Whats the reason you still want to support iOS 4.3? http://www.engadget.com/2015/01/07/apple-gains-smartphone-market-share-ios-8-adoption-up-to-68/

Comment: Due to business management decision which I have no say, even if I want to support iOS 5 onwards, is there a way for this?

Comment: Even big business these days are dropping support for even iOS 6.x. The reason is cost of implementation/maintaining these old versions. Just asking, have business management considered that.

Comment: I had mentioned it to the management and their sayings are they wish to support iPhone 4 (which earliest OS version is iOS 4.3).